# jqplot Meter Gauge Replot not working

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I'm new to charting and js and don't have much experience with js and jqplot so maybe someone can help me out?

I try to replot a jqplot meter gauge when the browser window is resized. I could find some examples during my research that seem to work fine but as soon as I try it myself, I can't make it work.

Here is my code:
[A fiddle can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/zt28pqxf/)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

   s1 = [72];

   var plot0 = $.jqplot('chart0',[s1],{
   seriesDefaults: {
       renderer: $.jqplot.MeterGaugeRenderer,
       rendererOptions: {
           label: 'Your Score is <div class="score">' + s1 + '</div>', //Showing the value 
           labelPosition: 'bottom',
           min: 0,
           max: 100,
           intervals:[30, 60, 80, 100],
           intervalColors:['#cc6666', '#E7E658', '#93b75f', '#66cc66'],
           ringColor: '#737373',
           ringWidth: 0.00000000001,           
           background :"transparent",
           intervalInnerRadius: 95,
           hubRadius: 6,
           showTicks: false,
           needleThickness: 5, 
           showTickLabels: false,

       }
   }
   });


 $(window).resize(function() {
      plot0.replot( { resetAxes: true } );
});


});
```

Maybe someone can see what I'm doing wrong? Any help is highly appreciated! I'm totally frustrated :(

### UPDATE

So I read again through all the documents and found this little sentence on the jqplot homepage:

"A meterGauge plot does not support events."

So I guess it just won't work whatever I do?
Any other idea how to make the jqplot meter gauge responsive?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, we finally found a solution.

For anybody else interested in the topic, here is how we did it in the end.

```
<script>

var plot0;
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#chart0').html('');
  plotGauge();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  plotGauge();  
});

s1 = [22]

function plotGauge(){
    plot0 = $.jqplot('chart0',[s1],{
  seriesDefaults: {
      renderer: $.jqplot.MeterGaugeRenderer,
      rendererOptions: {
           label: 'Your Score is <div class="score">' + s1 + '</div>', //Showing the value
           labelPosition: 'bottom',
           min: 0,
           max: 100,
           intervals:[30, 60, 80, 100],
           intervalColors:['#cc6666', '#E7E658', '#93b75f', '#66cc66'],
           ringColor: '#737373',
           ringWidth: 0.00000000001,
           background :"transparent",
           intervalInnerRadius: 95,
           hubRadius: 6,
           showTicks: false,
           needleThickness: 5,
           showTickLabels: false,
      }
  }
  });
}

</script>

  <div id="chart0"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution had problem with animation of graph(update data and replot), because when you have updated the data before resizing, again it shows from starting.So, you have to update the data before replot the graph.

But i found one more solution for this graph(i don't know what exact problem with graph), but somehow i had managed the graph replot by adding some dummy data to replot function. Please follow the below snippet.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    plot0.replot( { resetAxes: true, dummy:'dummy' });
});
```

The above snippet is working fine, and is best instead of creating new object. 
Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem with Gauge replot.

What I did is passed a dummy parameter to replot and it worked for me.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    plot0.replot( { resetAxes: true, dummy: 'dummy' } );
});
```

I didn't dig into the jqPlot code, will open an issue in free time.